# Generating csv format table in R

Tags: r

So I have a .csv file formatted as such:

```
Student,Grade
Steven,48
Tori,79
James,92
Elise,44
```

So I read it into R and manipulate the data a bit:

```
data = read.csv("/path/to/my.csv")
grades = data$Grade
grades = grades + 10
```

All I need to do now is write these new grades back to the grade column of my.csv, while preserving the formatting of the original csv (and the names). What is the most simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the data back into the data.frame:

```
data$Grade <- grades   ## you can actually skip the middle step here
```

Use `write.table()` with the correct settings:

```
write.table(data, file="/path/to/csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: You can also just use `write.csv` to save from using the `sep` argument.

Comment: Well I'll be damned! Why did I think that only `write.table` was an option? Maybe because there is no `write.delim`. Thanks @Thomas

Answer (score 2):

```
data$Grade <- data$Grade + 10
write.csv(data, file="/out/file/path.csv")
```

Comment: (+1) Minor detail, but the OP's column name is `Grade` with no `s`.